# how to fetch json data in scope variable angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

Here is my Json data

```
"data": {
      "address": {
        "postalCode": "112629",
        "state": "DL",
        "city": "new city",
        "streetAddress": "my street"
      },
     "specialities": [
        {
          "_id": "577692f7",
          "name": "Football",
          "description": "game",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ]
    }
```

$scope.test  = data;
i am fetching data in html by 
ng-repeat="mytest in test" than

```
mytest.address.city // this is working fine
mytest.specialities.name // not printing anything
```

i am facing the problem in accessing the specialities name i think that is because of specialities is a array but don't know how to get it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2):

You defined a specialities object with only one array inside

try

```
mytest.specialities[0].name
```

**Update**:

Also you may want to make sure that the array has at least one element, otherwise you mayget a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

So the code sould look like this:

`mytest.specialities.length > 0 ? mytest.specialities[0].name : '(some default value)';`

Comment: Thanks for comment. you are right this is the way but what if i have more than one entries of specialties and i don't know how many are there like someone has 3 someone has 4 that how will i fetch.

Comment: with a loop in your object then you will have mytest.specialities[loopindex].name
Or like @Arif wrote

Answer (score 0):

Yes **mytest.specialities** is array. JSON has two possible options **[ ]** - array, **{ }** - object. In this situation we have array of objects - **[ { /* object data */ } ]** so to get object parameter first go to array element like this ( example getting first element on index 0 ):

```
mytest.specialities[0].name
```

second element:

```
mytest.specialities[1].name
```

example each:

```
<div  ng-repeat="special in mytest.specialities">
    <span>{{special.name}}</span>
</div>
```

of course before that set mytest to scope like:

```
$scope.mytest=mytest;//mytest is your data structure
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there will be many specialities you should use ng-repeat to display them all.

```
<p ng-repeat="s in mytest.specialities"> {{s.name}} / {{s._id}} / {{s.description}} </p>
```